# Gerar array com conteúdo da table com jquery

Tags: jquery, array, table, each

Olá

estou tentando recuperar os elementos de uma tabela e passar pra um array jquery que será usado no ajax

eu crio as td dinamicamente:

```
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";

        cols += '<td class="tdProductId" id='+ $("#product option").attr("id") +'>'+ $("#product option").text() +'</td>';
        cols += '<td class="tdProductAmount">'+ $("input[name=amount]").val() +'</td>';
        cols += '<td class="tdProductPrice">'+ $("input[name=price]").val() +'</td>';
        cols += '<td class="tdProductTotal">'+ $("input[name=price]").val() * $("input[name=amount]").val() +'</td>';
        cols += '<td>';
        cols += '<a href="#" class="removeProduct">Remover</a>';
        cols += '</td>';

        newRow.append(cols);
        $("#input_stock_product").append(newRow);
```

O problema é recuperar o attr de uma td e o texto das outra e por em um array
O que tentei fazer, porém, ele n cria outros índices no array, e acaba juntando os valores tudo:

```
        var productsData = { 
            id_product: $(".tdProductId").attr("id"),
            amount:  $(".tdProductAmount").text(),
            price: $(".tdProductPrice").text(),
            total: $(".tdProductTotal").text()
        };
```

Desta forma ele me retorna um objeto, ex:

```
Object {id_product: "137", amount: "12", price: "11", total: "132"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você precisará adicionar uma classe ao tr. Então use o método each nessa classe para pegar cada linha adicionada, e tratá-la com a referência $(this).

Exemplificando:
https://jsfiddle.net/64azsg33/

Comment: tem alguma ideia de como eu faria para inserir esse array em uma tabela com codeIgniter com ajax?

Comment: Sim, mas a resposta é extensa. Pode fazer uma nova pergunta? Assim poderemos ajudar mais usuários que tenham a mesma dúvida

Comment: aqui esta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123911/inserir-um-array-com-codeigniter-e-ajax

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode fazer assim:

```
    var arrayDeLinhas = [];

    $("tbody > tr").each(function(index,tr){
        arrayDeLinhas.push(  { 
            id_product: $(tr).find(".tdProductId").attr("id"),
            amount:  $(tr).find(".tdProductAmount").text(),
            price: $(tr).find(".tdProductPrice").text(),
            total: $(tr).find(".tdProductTotal").text()
        });
    });

    console.log(arrayDeLinhas);
```

Repare que a busca das linhas é feita através de um elemento tbody. Caso não tenha utilizado esta tag(Deveria) em sua tabela. Troque pelo identificador da tabela. Supondo que o seletor que você utilzou para adicionar uma linha, seja o identificador da tabela, utilize desta forma:

```
    $("#input_stock_product > tr").each(function(index,tr){...
```