# Inserir um array com codeIgniter e ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, array, codeigniter, foreach

Olá

estou tentando inserir um array, mas neste caso, poderá inserir múltiplas linhas no db.

Como passo os dados pro codeIgniter:

```
            var productsData = [];
        $(".productRow").each(function(i){
            var pData = { 
                id_product: $(this).find(".tdProductId").attr("id"),
                amount:  $(this).find(".tdProductAmount").text(),
                price: $(this).find(".tdProductPrice").text()
            };
            productsData.push(pData);
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo site_url('/StockController/createInputStock')?>",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                id_people: $("#people option").attr("id"),
                type: $("#stock_type").val(),
                date: $("input[name=date]").val(),
                products: JSON.stringify(productsData)
            },
            success: function(data){
                Materialize.toast(data, 4000);
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                Materialize.toast('Erro ao adicionar uma nova entrada de estoque!', 4000);
            }
        });
    });
```

Controller:

```
    public function createInputStock(){
    $people = array(
        'input_date' => $this->input->post('date'),
        'input_type' => $this->input->post('type'),
        'id_people' => $this->input->post('id_people')
        );
    if($this->StockModel->createInputStockPeople('stock_input',$people)){
        $product = array(
            'id_product' => $this->input->post('id_people'),
            'unit_price' => $this->input->post('id_people'),
            'amount' => $this->input->post('id_people'),
            'id_stock' => '51'
            );
        foreach ($product as $products) {
            if($this->StockModel->createInputStockProduct('stock_input_products', $products)){
                echo "foi";
            }else{
                echo "deu pau";
            }
        }

    }else{
        echo "Erro ao adicionar a pessoa";
    }
}
```

Models:

```
    public function createInputStockPeople($table, $peopleData){
    $this->db->insert($table, $peopleData);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
public function createInputStockProduct($table, $produtctData){
    return $this->db->insert($table, $produtctData);
}
```

Como podem ver, é inserido apenas uma linha na tabela `stock_input` (e isto já esta funcionadno) o problema é para depois inserir varias na tabela `stock_input_products`

Comment: Bem, do método que você está fazendo já está passando os dados para o codeigniter, inclusive inserindo-os no banco de dados. O que está dando errado?

Comment: simplesmente não inseri na stock_input_products, aquele array product está certo? 
Ele me retorna a msg do error do ajax

Comment: Pode adicionar a mensagem de erro a pergunta?